# Build request failed with message: [ERROR] RAPC exception occurred

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I was packaging and launching my application in blackberry Webworks SDK and I got this big red error:

> Build request failed with message: [ERROR] RAPC exception occurred

What does that mean?

My Package settings:

- **SDK Path**: C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry 
  WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5
- **Project Root**: C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\HelloWorld
- **Archive Name**: HelloWorld
- **Output Folder**: C:\Users\ejobity\Documents\Blackberry Development
  \projects\apps\HelloWorld
- **Simulator**: 9930-7.0.0.318

MS DOS say

> Error: java compiler failed: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_0 7\bin\javac.exe
>   @C:\Users\ejobity\AppData\Local\Temp\rapc_6eb ...
>
> 2012-10-07 15:53:53 GET /ripple/build_status/8442 200 out: [ERROR]
>   RAPC exception occurred
>
> Done build error response - {"code":1,"msg":"[ERROR]     \t\tRAPC
>   exception occurred\n","da ta":null}

Comment: "RAPC exception occurred"  You need to find the actual exception message, otherwise all anyone can tell you is that your compiler ran into an exception, which you already know.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change from JDK 1.7 to JDK 1.6 and run the CMD like administrator.

If you uninstall JDK 1.7, and later you install JDK 1.6 after that, you have to uninstall BlackBerry WebWorks and reinstall it.  This is because WebWorks has its own path to JDK and JRE, and if you don't reinstall it, these new paths won't update, and you will continue with problems.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're using JDK 1.7.  You should be using 1.6 (and make sure it's the 32bit version, not the 64bit as well).

Here's a link to [JDK 1.6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6u35-downloads-1836443.html)